# How to automatically indent the JavaScript code in Aptana Studio?

Tags: javascript, aptana, indentation, auto-indent

Previously I used Eclipse for PHP and Java development, and I liked the command `Ctrl + i` to automatically indent the code.

Now am I using Aptana Studio that is based on Eclipse, for JavaScript development. I would like to automatically indent my JavaScript code, but `Ctrl + i` deletes all my code. Is there any other command that automatically indent JavaScript code in Aptana Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Studio does not have this feature yet. You can add a feature request here: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/new

Ctrl+Shift+F will format your entire file, as Tim suggested.
You can control some of the formatter settings through the preferences at 'Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Formatter'

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+F` seem to work good for PHP, but it doesn't seem to work for JavaScript.

Comment: It should also work for JS. If you got an error in the log, you can open ticket with some code sample that trigger it and we'll fix it :)

Comment: @Jonas solution works for me in Aptana 3.4.2 for JS. Question is pretty old so I figure it was added meanwhile.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you mean format feature `CTRL+SHIFT+F`?

Comment: Oh, no, I tried this command for PHP now, and it changed everything. Before I had my lines at maximum 80 chars, but now they may be super long. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This worked for me to indent javascript code. thanks. at someplaces like if and else statement... the indentation is packing. but its alright for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've just updated to Aptana Studio 3.0.9 and it now seems to be able to format specific (selected) lines of JavaScript, HTML and CSS, in some circumstances.  The default key binding for me was something odd so I changed the key binding to `CTRL+I` in `Preferences > General > Keys`.

If no code is selected then `Source > Format` seems to always reliably format the entire file.  The behaviour of `Source > Format` on *selections* differs depending on the type of code you're editing:

**JavaScript**

- **Editing a .js file**: `Source > Format` appears to work as you'd expect: if you select a few lines of code then `Source > Format` will correctly indent just the selected lines of code.
- **Editing JavaScript within HTML**: Formatting JavaScript within an HTML file appears to work most of the time but sometimes fails; I have not been able to discover the rules.

**HTML**

- If you select a chunk of HTML, AND IF the top line of that selection is correctly indented ALREADY, AND IF the selection does not include any unclosed elements then `Source > Format` will do the right thing.
- Otherwise `Source > Format` seems to act unpredictably with HTML.

**CSS**

- **Editing a .css file**:

  - works fine if I select an entire rule (i.e. including all of `selector { declaration block; }`) (in which case Aptana formats just that rule).
  - But if my selection does not include the entire rule then I get an error.
- **Editing css within HTML**:

  - If *part* of the CSS is selected within a `<style>` block then `source > format` will format *all* the css within that `<style>` block.  There seems to be no way to format just a few lines of css within html.

Unless anyone points out that this post contains fatal flaws within the next few days, I'll post a feature request at https://jira.appcelerator.org to ask for consistency in formatting behaviour across code types (a quick look at the existing feature and bug requests suggests that code formatting has received a considerable amount of attention recently).

*update 19/3/2012* I've posted this bug on the JIRA: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4516

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and stumbled across this site:
[jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)
You might wanna check it out. Worked fine for me ;)