# Eclipse Indigo with Syntax Highlighting for HTML/JS/CSS etc

Tags: html, css, eclipse, pydev, highlighting

I'm using Eclipse Indigo with PyDev for python development tasks
and I'm unable to get highlighting to work for HTML/CSS/JS and the like files.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Thanks in advance
Oli

Comment: @Manny: [It's still on topic here.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: oh sorry 'bout that, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be getting Aptana Studio 3 (I recommend getting the standalone version, but if you decide installing it as a plugin, you'll have to uninstall PyDev before -- because Aptana Studio 3 is a superset which already integrates PyDev).

See: http://pydev.org/download.html for links.

Comment: I don't want to use Aptana because it doesn't work with openjdk

Comment: Have you tried reporting that as a bug? (I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work in openjdk -- note that if the vm is crashing, it's probably a bug in the vm and not in aptana studio 3).

Comment: Aptana is very bad, it doesn't even have [auto indentation for JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138115/how-to-automatically-indent-the-javascript-code-in-aptana-studio) and if you use it on the same project as with Eclipse, it will overwrite all your color settings and destroy the look.